# Cannot validate Chosen select with jQuery Validate (not unobtrusive)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I am trying to make simple DropDownList validation (clear jQuery - no unobtrusive) in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

I have fields in model:

```
[DisplayName("Wybierz płatnika")]
public virtual int? studyPayerId { get; set; }
public virtual IList<StudyPayer> PayersList { get; set; }
```

Then in controller I do:

```
var payers = RisDbPersistanceManager.RetrieveEquals<StudyPayer>("IsActive", true); 
if (payers != null)
{
  model.PayersList = payers;  // it is populated                 
}
model.studyPayerId = null;
```

And in my View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

...

$('#studyPayerId').rules('add',
{
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Proszę wybrać płatnika!"
    }
});    
...
<div class="formsElement" >
  <div class="formsElementLabel" >
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.studyPayerId)
  </div>
  <div class="formsElementInput" >
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.studyPayerId, new SelectList(Model.PayersList, "Id", "Name", Model.studyPayerId), "-- wybierz płatnika --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.studyPayerId)
  </div>
</div>
```

In simple TextBox fields everything works - validates my field on Submit button click. But DropDownList does not display any message when I did not choose anything and leave "-- wybierz płatnika --" selection.

### EDIT

```
  <select id="Gender" class="error" name="Gender" style="display: none;">
  <label class="error" for="Gender">Proszę wybrać płeć!</label>
  <div id="Gender_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 127px;" title="">
    <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
    <span>-- nieokreślona --</span>
  <div>
  </a>
  <div class="chosen-drop" style="top: 34px; bottom: auto;">
</div>
```

Comment: Add the `[Required]` attribute to property `studyPayerId` and let `jquery-validate-unobtrusive` handle your client side validation (no need for the script!)

Comment: No difference, I have tried it before for inspection. But I need to turn off and on validation depending on some settings that's why I'm turn it on in jQuery.

Comment: Then use a [RequiredIf](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) attribute

Comment: Side note: The last parameter of you `SelectList` constructor ( `.., Model.studyPayerId`) is pointless since you binding to a property (its ignored by the html helper).

Comment: I also tried without that argument. I spend 6 hours on the code that why I am here. I don't know what is wrong. In other view it works also with DropDownList.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong (and adding the rules by it self wont work for unbtrusive validation which reads the `data-val-*` attributes of the controls). Post you html generated when you add the `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: There is something wrong with the html you posted - it generates `<option value>-- wybierz płatnika --</option>` (not `<option  value="">`)!

Comment: It is `<option value="">-- wybierz płatnika --</option>`

Comment: Not possible without something else at play. Can you confirm that `payers` contains only 3 elements.

Comment: Yes 3. I will paste some information from FireBug for a moment.

Comment: You said it works in other views. Check the html generated in them - I'm sure you will see `<option value>...`

Comment: HTML is the same, but there is no warnings that you can see in the print screen (last 3 warnings in jquery.validate.js files)

Comment: Too small to read! But its all very strange and I cant think of what might be causing the problem. All I can suggest is that you compare this view with those that are working to see if there are any obvious differences, or create a new test view and just include the `DropDownListFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` for `studyPayerId` with no other controls or scripts (except the jquery files)

Comment: I think the problem is: jQuery Validate do not validate hidden fields and <select> that keeps data in DropDownList is hidden

Comment: Your using a plugin for the select! Don't you think that was worth mentioning in the question!

Comment: I think DropDownList always keeps data in hidden <select>. Sorry for misconfusion...

Comment: A standard dropdownlist is not hidden! if it is, you have some other javascript code or plugin doing it.

Comment: DropDownList is build dynamicaly with <a> and <span> elements. And data is kept in "display: none;" <select>. Check new EDIT in question...

Comment: I suggest you edit the title of your question _Cannot validate DropDownList using Chosen Select plugin_ or similar

Comment: I agree with @StephenMuecke. **Neglecting to mention that the dropdown list is created by another plugin like Chosen was a huge failure by the OP.** This information was absolutely critical to answering this question properly and not wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is JavaScript so you'll need to show us the ***RENDERED*** and relevant HTML code as seen by the browser, not your model, view or controller.  Since I cannot see your rendered HTML, I use generic naming in my demo code below.

   - The first `option` element **must** have a `value=""` attribute.
   - The `select` element **must** have a `name` attribute even if you don't use it.
2. I don't see your call to the `.validate()` method.  The plugin ***must*** first get initialized with the `.validate()` method.  You cannot use the `.rules()` method without it.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate(); // <- INITIALIZE plugin

    $('#studyPayerId').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Proszę wybrać płatnika!"
        }
    });

});
```

**Rendered HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <select name="myselect" id="studyPayerId">
        <option value="">-- wybierz płatnika --</option>
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/nwLqdemu/**

---

I do not understand why you're using the `.rules()` method.  Usually that's is only used when rules need to be added and removed *dynamically*; or when rules get applied to an entire group of elements at once, because that would be too lengthy to be included within the `.validate()` method.

Otherwise, you'd simply declare rules within the `.validate()` method upon initialization...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // INITIALIZE plugin

    $('#myform').validate({ 
        rules: {
            myselect: {  // <- NAME attribute
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            myselect: {  // <- NAME attribute
                required: "Proszę wybrać płatnika!"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/nwLqdemu/1/**

---

**[Please see the SO Tag Wiki page for a basic demo and hints on proper usage.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info)**

---

**EDIT**:

Since you never mentioned using the "Chosen" plugin for creating your drop down list, there is no way anyone could have answered this question.  However, since the jQuery Validate plugin ignores hidden elements by default, you'll need to change the `ignore` option to `[]` in order to "ignore nothing" and validate the element hidden by Chosen.

Comment: The problem was there: DropDownList keeps its data in hidden <select> list and jQueryValidate by default do not validate hidden fields. Solution was to add  `$('#myForm').validate().settings.ignore = [];`. Thanks for time given.

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki, how could anyone know the select was being created by Chosen since you never mentioned it in the original question?  Furthermore, you are continuing to use jQuery Validate as if you have `unobtrusive` installed.  Since you stated that you are not using `unobtrusive`, I've tried to show you how to properly use the plugin.